# Time discretization of the variational formulation of the Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: finite-element, pde, numerical-analysis, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

> *I've asked [this question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263008/time-discretization-of-the-variational-formulation-of-the-navier-stokes-equation) too*.

Let

- $T>0$
- $I:=(0,T]$
- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be nonempty and open, $$\mathcal V:=\left\{\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d):\nabla\cdot\phi=0\right\}$$ and $$V:=\overline{\mathcal V}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{H^1(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}}\;,\;\;\;H:=\overline{\mathcal V}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}}$$
- $\operatorname P_H$ denote the orthogonal projection from
  $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ onto $H$
- $A_0u:=-\Delta u$ for $u\in\mathcal D(A_0):=H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\cap H^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$, $$Au:=\operatorname P_HA_0u\;\;\;\text{for }u\in\mathcal D(A):=\mathcal D(A_0)\cap V$$ and $$B(u,v):=(u\cdot\nabla)v\;\;\;\text{for }u\in L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\text{ and }v\in H^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$$
- $f:I\to H$
- $u\in L^2(I,\mathcal D(A))$ with $u'\in L^2(I,H)$ and $$u'(t)+A_0u(t)+B(u(t),u(t))+\nabla p(t)=f(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\tag1$$ for some $p:I\to H^1(\Lambda)$

> Assuming that $\Lambda$ is sufficiently regular such that $(1)$ is well-defined, it can be shown that $(1)$ is equivalent to $$u'(t)+Au(t)+\operatorname P_HB(u(t),u(t))=f(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\;.\tag2$$ I want to solve $(2)$ numerically and I'm only interested in $u$ (and not in $p$).

I know that there are many references for the numerical study of $(1)$. However, it seems to me that all the considered schemes don't use $(2)$. They only use $(2)$ for theoretical results like existence and uniqueness of solutions. Maybe I'm wrong and I just don't see that these schemes use $(2)$.

> In any case, my question is: Are we able to provide a numerical scheme which solves $(2)$ directly?

Or is there something which prevents us from doing that? My idea is to apply, for example, a semi-implicit Oseen discretization in time, i.e. consider $$\frac{u(t_n)-u(t_{n-1})}h+Au(t_n)+\operatorname P_HB(u(t_{n-1}),u(t_n))=f(t_n)\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\left\{1,\ldots,N\right\}\tag3$$ with $$t_n:=nh\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\left\{0,\ldots,N\right\}$$ and $h:=T/N$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$. After that for each $n\in\left\{1,\ldots,N\right\}$ $(3)$ should be solvable by a finite element method (or is there some problem that I don't see?).

Comment: A quick google search turned up these:
http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/030601533
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X85903300
I'm not sure if they're what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Unfortunately not. I'm looking for a reference where the time discretization of $(1)$ is tested against divergence-free test functions. The construction of a practicable scheme where the finite element
functions are exactly divergence-free seems to be nontrivial.

Comment: Are you aware of Nedelec elements?  Are they not what you're looking for?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson No, I wasn't and, until now, I'm not sure if they are what I'm looing for. tThe motivation for my question was the following: In a [dissertation](https://publikationen.uni-tuebingen.de/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10900/49705/pdf/diss_main_pub.pdf?sequence=1) (see the fourth paragraph at page 38 (in the PDF-ordering)), I've read that "it is nontrivial to construct practicable numerical schemes where finite el
ement functions are exactly divergence-free". I just don't understand *why* this is nontrivial.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I could imagine, that the reason is due to the approximation of the pressure (in which I'm not interested). After a time discretization has ben chosen, I don't see the problem to consider weak formulations as they are stated in [this lecture note](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam04-12.pdf) (see page 50 (in the PDF-ordering)).

Comment: Maybe the dissertation mentions that the condition is satisfied in the weak sense.

Comment: @nicoguaro It's satisfied in the sense that $\langle\nabla\cdot u,p\rangle_{L^2}=0$ for all $p\in L^2$ with $\int_\Lambda p=0$. But they don't eliminate the pressure from the equation $(1)$ and hence need to compute both the velocity $u$ and the pressure $p$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented `a semi-implicit Oseen discretization in time` numerical scheme using Mathematica FEM  and tested it on the problems of thermal convection and flow around an aerodynamic profile. Coincidence with other methods is generally good. A detailed report along with the code can be viewed at
https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064
I also used a similar numerical scheme for compressible and turbulent flows. For example, 3D turbulent flow in a rectangular channel with jump section
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217202/transition-to-turbulence

My opinion is that nothing wrong with this algorithm as I tested it and compare with other numerical methods.

Answer (score 0):

The *something* that prevents me from using such a scheme with projections is the numerical realization of the projector $P_H\colon L^2 \to H$.

- I don't know of a formulation that is better accessible to numerical algorithms than expression of the projection via
  $$
  v_0 = P_Hv \leftrightarrow 
  \begin{bmatrix}I & \nabla \\ div & 0\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}v_0 \\ *\end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}v \\ 0\end{bmatrix},
  $$
  where the $*$ is a dummy variable,
- which I would approximate by means of *mixed finite elements*,
- which (probably) would realize $(3)$ as a standard *mixed FEM* of the Navier-Stokes in the $(v,p)$-formulation.

So... **If you have a reasonable numerical realization of $P_H$, there is nothing wrong with the scheme sketched in $(3)$.**

Comment: You don't need a realization of $\operatorname P_H$. If we test $(1)$ against $v\in V$, we obtain $$\frac1h\langle u^n-u^{n-1},v\rangle_H+\mathfrak a(u^n,v)+\mathfrak b(u^{n-1},u^n,v)=\langle f^n,v\rangle_H\;,$$ where $u^n:=u(t_n)$, $f^n:=f(t_n)$, $$\mathfrak a(u,v):=\sum_{i=1}^d\langle\nabla u_i,\nabla v_i\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:ℝ^d)}\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in H_0^1(Λ,ℝ^d)$$ and $$\mathfrak b(u,v,w):=\langle B(u,v),w\rangle_{L^2(Λ,\:ℝ^d)}\;\;\;\text{for }u,v,w\in H_0^1(Λ,ℝ^d)\;.\tag 4$$

Comment: The crucial point is that testing $(3)$ against $v$ yields $(3)$ too. So, this simply corresponds to choosing a finite element space of divergence-free functions. (cf. chapter 5 of [this lecture notes](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam04-12.pdf))

Comment: So... what **is** your question.... Do *divergence-free* test functions exist and why does no one use them??  We have added some discussion and references on this issue in our paper: Altmann/H. [*Finite element decomposition and minimal extension for flow equations*](http://www.esaim-m2an.org/articles/m2an/abs/2015/05/m2an141025/m2an141025.html) (postprint on my homepage)

Comment: I've asked a [question on the steady Navier-Stokes problem](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26279/numerical-computation-of-the-velocity-in-the-steady-navier-stokes-equation) in the hope that things are clearer over there. In the enumeration of that question, I wonder why everybody is using $(1)$ and hence is dealing with mixed finite elements, while we could also use $(2)$ and hence would only need to deal with the space $V$.

Comment: From another perspective: The approach related to $(1)$ is finding a solution $u\in H_0^1$ of the first equation of $(1)$ and enforcing $\nabla\cdot u=0$ by the second equation of $(1)$, i.e. $u\in V$. If we don't care about the pressure $p$, why don't we search a solution $u\in V$ of the first equation of $(1)$ and test against functions from $V$ (such that the problem is completely described in $V$); which leads immediately to $(2)$.

Comment: Because consistent apprx. of $V$ are not practical.

Comment: That's what I heard, but the question is: *Why* are they not practical? Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: Come on, that's not the question that you posted. I suggest, you come to terms with what you want to know and make it a question here. I would also like to see answers on 'Why does no one use div-free elements?'. My take on that is summarized in the article that I mentioned above.

Comment: It's exactly the question that I posted. $(3)$ leads to the variational problem in $V$ that I stated in my first comment. What I wanted to know is, if we're able to solve this problem numerically. You say that it's not practical, cause consistent approximations of $V$ are not practical. I can't find the answer to that question in your article.

Comment: Well, I don't see from your question, why (3) is to be approximated consistently. Anyways, in my paper is what I know. In the provided reference there is a whole chapter on that.

Comment: You mean chapter 3.1?

Comment: No, the introduction.